# C# Winform Listview selected item issue

Tags: c#, winforms, listview

I'm trying to copy the selected item's filename and its path to the clipboard and then a textbox from a listview. I can't seem to get this one to work how i want. Here's the code I've been playing around with.

```
private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (listView1.Items.Count > 0)
    {
        listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
        Clipboard.SetDataObject(this.listView1.SelectedItems[0]);
        textBox1.Paste();
    }
}
```

Can someone get me on the right track?

Comment: Why are you using the clipboard instead of just setting the `Text` of textBox1?

Comment: @Austin Salonen  - I have another function that needs a similar functionality that requires me to copy the data to the clipboard. I do understand that it can easily be done without. I just wanted to kill two birds with one stone. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (listView1.SelectedItems.Count > 0) {
            textBox1.Text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
        }
        else {
            textBox1.Text = string.Empty;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! at first I added this code to my form and I still got no result. So i created a new project and create a quick test form and it worked. I have to correct the other issue with my form.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you're using the Clipboard here.  You can do just fine without it.

```
listView1.Items[0].Selected = true;
textBox1.Text = this.listView1.SelectedItems[0].ToString();
```